# HTTP 302 redirects fail when using URLConnection in Java, possibly due to load balancer

Tags: java, redirect, load-balancing, urlconnection

I have the following code snippet

```
...
URLConnection conn = sampleURL.openConnection();
int len = conn.getContentLength();
...
```

Most of the times, when sampleURL sends a 302 redirect response, I see that the above code successfully calls the new URL and fetches the response from there.

However, there are times when the above code fails (i.e) a 302 redirect response is received from sampleURL but the actual redirect never happens. In the Apache logs on the calling side, I see the 302 redirect response being logged, but nothing after that. The call to the new URL is never logged.

I have seen this happening primarily when the application which runs the above code is behind a load balancer, but I'm not sure if this is actually the reason for the problem.

Has anyone faced this issue ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: An HTTP redirect directs the client to issue a new request to the specified URL in order to retrieve the requested resource.  It is up to the client whether to actually issue such a request -- you cannot assume it will do.  If the web server issuing such a redirect is behind a load balancer, then it is up to the LB whether a followup request hits the same back-end server or one of its peers.  LBs *can* try to pin clients to the same server, but they are not required to do, and they do not necessarily do so by default.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In my scenario, the server code that is being called is not behind a load balancer, but instead the client application that makes the call runs behind a load balancer.

Comment: Load balancing in this context applies to *incoming* requests.  A machine being among a group of load-balanced peers serving requests over the network should not have any bearing at all on any *outgoing* connections that machine initiates or on any traffic over such a connection.  If it does then your LB is misconfigured or stupid.

Comment: Conceivably an LB could cause such an issue, though, by routing the redirect response to a different machine than the one that issued the original request.  In that case, though, you would expect the same thing to happen sometimes to ordinary responses.  The effects of such issues are likely to be more visible on the HTTP client side than on the server side -- if the clients are not seeing any hangs or timeouts on their HTTP requests, then it is not likely the LB in front of them that's causing the issues.

Comment: If the clients are in some kind of automatically managed pool, though, then it may be that occasionally one is shut down at just such a time that it ignores a redirect response to one of its requests.